# If you already have an Ingress account, is there any set point that you get invite codes to give to others?

Tags: ingress

Does it happen at a certain level, some amount of time spent playing, or are they handed out ad-hoc?

Comment: To the close voter: I don't think this is too localized as there are thousands of players who the answer would apply to, and Google has not stated a public release date - it could be private beta for some time.

Comment: Would love to know; can't invite anyone and it would be nice to play with friends.

Answer (score 3):

I've made it to level 3 without acquiring an invite to give. I'll let you know if and when I do.

By the way, the ingress.com/intel webapp is way faster than the ingress scanner app for just checking if you have any invites or not.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the invites were given out ad-hoc.
Once all level 7+ got 3 invites to give out.
Recently all level 2+ (maybe 1+) got 5 invites to give out.